# Which interface should be used for communication between processors?

Tags: communication, ethernet

I have two processors (STM and Infineon) on the same board and I have to organize communication between them. Yet I'm using Ethernet to communicate between them, but a startup time of Ethernet after turning on takes to much time (~2s). Could I setup communication over Ethernet without PHY drivers and so decrease the startup time?

If it's impossible, which interface can I use instead of it? The main requirements: fast startup time - 100 - 200 ms and communication speed not less than 10 Mb/s.

EDIT: I'm using [STM32F407](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f407-417.html?querycriteria=productId=LN11) and [Infineon TriCore TC234](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontroller/32-bit-tricore-tm-microcontroller/aurix-tm-family/aurix-tm-family-%E2%80%93-tc23xl/channel.html?channel=db3a304342c787030142dbf5292a1522)

Comment: What options have you considered so far?

Comment: SPI, USB, there are many options to choose from.

Comment: Infineon doesn't have USB interface

Comment: And what about Ethernet communication without PHY drivers?

Comment: I've seen two DSPs communicate on on the same board via TCP/IP over a SPORT link. If both processors have compatible interfaces there is no need for the ethernet PHY.

Comment: The overhead with TCP seems out of place here.  Why not SPI?  It's fast (enough) and simple low-level.  How heavy is the communication?

Comment: How did you connect the processors over Ethernet? Do they have MAC interfaces? Normally MAC-MAC connections are indeed possible.

Comment: At yet each processor connected to own PHY driver and they communicates over cable: STM--->PHY-->RJ45<------->RJ45<--PHY<--Infineon

Comment: I don't need TCP/IP transmits, MAC to MAC will be enough.

Comment: Since they are on the same board, I would go for SPI.

Answer (score 2):

At 10 Mbit/s, you can use SPI, maybe two separate busses, one for each direction.  Or, you can roll your own interface with maybe 8 parallel data lines and a few handshaking lines.

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturers such as IDT and Cypress make dual-port RAM chips that make it easy for two processors to exchange messages with minimal software overhead. They also make FIFO chips — a pair of which would accomplish the same thing with fewer pins.

I work with FPGAs a lot; I would be tempted to use a small one to create a shared memory that has dual SPI interfaces.

I2S buses can also be used to stream data at such speeds. What about SDIO? Really, this would be a lot easier if you told us exactly which chips you're using, and which hardware resources are still available in your design.

Comment: Infineon doesn't implement SDOI. I edited my question and told about processors.

Comment: That's a start -- and I added links for you. But which resources are you not already using in your design?

Answer (score 0):

An Ethernet communication between two devices acting both as MACs without using PHYs in between is actually possible. I have seen it and used it.

But not all MAC devices support something like this. You have to clarify this with the specific processors that you have.

Otherwise SPI would be a good choice as an alternative interface.

Comment: How I could understand, that the communication without PHY is possible?

Comment: If it isn't explicitly stated and also no application note or sth similar exists, then I would ask the customer support of ST and Infineon!

Comment: If your MACs support 1000BaseX (SGMII without autonegotiation), the MAC side and PHY side are symmetric and so you can directly connect two MACs.